# SQLAlchemy Order joined table by field in another joined table

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

My project requires that Orders are split into their individual lines which can be displayed in their own views I want these views to order the lines by eta which is a value in the Order table.

I have 3 tables with a 1>1 join on tables 1&2 and a many>many join on tables 2 and 3 defined by table 4 as follows:

```
class Order(db.Model):  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    eta = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    order_lines = db.relationship('Line', backref='order', order_by=lambda: Line.id)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Order No. {}>'.format(self.increment_id)

class Line(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    line_name = db.Column(db.String())
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'))
    product_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('product.product_id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Line SKU: {}>'.format(self.line_sku)

class Line_view(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    view_name = db.Column(db.String())
    view_lines  = relationship('Line', 
        secondary='line_view_join', 
        backref='views',
        lazy='dynamic',
        order_by= ***???*** ) #ordery by eta on Order table
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<View: {}>'.format(self.view_name)

class Line_view_join(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'line_view_join'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    line_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('line.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    view_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('line_view.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

I am trying to work out how to query table 3, Line_View and have the joined Lines ordered by the eta of Order table.

Such that when querying:

```
chosen_view = Line_view.query.filter_by(id = 1).one()
```

`chosen_view.view_lines` are ordered by `Order.eta`

I have Tried

```
class Line_view(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    view_name = db.Column(db.String())
    view_lines  = relationship('Line', 
        secondary='line_view_join', 
        backref='views',
        lazy='dynamic',
        **order_by=lambda: asc(Line.order.eta))**
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<View: {}>'.format(self.view_name)
```

But this results in the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Line.order has an attribute 'eta'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the Line_views in the database? If not, you can query the Lines sorted by the eta attribute of the related order. Below, I create two orders with one line each, and then query the lines sorted by the eta attribute of their order:

```
eta = datetime(2019,10,10)
o = Order(eta = eta)
l = Line(order=o, line_name="sample")
db.session.add(o)
db.session.add(l)

eta = datetime(2019,11,11)
o1 = Order(eta = eta)
l1 = Line(order=o1, line_name="sample1")
db.session.add(o1)
db.session.add(l1)
db.session.commit()

lines = Line.query.join(Order).order_by(Order.eta)
```

Comment: Yes line_views was many-many joined to lines. So for example, line_view = "Needs Engraving" this view would contain all lines from all orders which need engraving. ideally sorted by the orders delivery eta so that they can be engraved in order. There are a few work arounds of course. Temporarily I am using 2 separate queries, 1 for the line_view (production_view would be a better name!) and one for the view itself but I was wondering if there was a cleaner single query which would let me directly access line_view.lines with ordering. I am beginning to think there may not be.